# Cannot detect CD rom on Lubuntu 17.10.1

Tags: cd

I just loaded Lubunto 17.10.1. Cannot read CD rom. When I load the CD, can hear the typical sound of it running and then it stops. But there no pop of the CD directory. What should I do?

Comment: Is this a new install or upgrade?

Comment: If you've correctly passed the cdrom device, you should be able to mount it like this.sudo -i 
mount /dev/cdrom /mnt/cdrom 
cd /mnt

Comment: You state "when I load the CD can hear the typical sound" which I gather is the spinning of the drive. This is done by hardware, and occurs on many drives if they just have power connected but aren't connected to a PC (if the drive won't spin reliably they spit disc out - its this check you're hearing).  To use the cd/dvd you need to mount it (unless enabled as automatic). It's more secure to only `mount` devices when you authorize/direct it to.  On my Ubuntu I just installed a dvdr & saw and heard it spin up, but I had to load a file.manager and select drive before I could view files on it.

Comment: Thanks all. Yes its a new install. Also I'm new to lubuntu, have only used windows and am a novice. I tried the command line and it gave an error. However I can view the CD in accessories-disk

Comment: Guys, its working now. I tried sudo mkdir -p /mnt/cdrom/  Also clicked mount partition in accessories--> disk for the dvd drive